# How can I run a java web applet directly from my desktop without opening it in a browser?

Tags: windows, java

I have a work application that I need to run occasionally, and we're provided with a url that loads a page with nothing but the object tag pointing at some remote jar file. Obviously, I already have the JRE installed.

Is there a way to get this to run directly (in Windows)? If it were a jnlp file, I'd just do a `c:\path\to\javaws.exe http://something.edu/blah.jnlp` and it would work as expected. But this is a plain jar file.

The markup for the applet is as follows:

```
<PARAM NAME="TYPE"       VALUE="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6.0_12">
<PARAM NAME="CODEBASE"   VALUE="/forms/java">
<PARAM NAME="CODE"       VALUE="oracle.forms.engine.Main" >
<PARAM NAME="ARCHIVE"    VALUE="frmall.jar" > 
<PARAM NAME="serverURL" VALUE="/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=/forms/frmservlet?config=pdev&#38;ifsessid=WLS_FORMS1.formsapp.1090&#38;acceptLanguage=en-US,en;q=0.8">
<PARAM NAME="networkRetries" VALUE="0">
<PARAM NAME="serverArgs" 
       VALUE="escapeParams=true module=test.fmx userid=  debug=no host= port= obr=no record= tracegroup= log= term= ssoProxyConnect=no iamticket= ">
<PARAM NAME="separateFrame" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="splashScreen"  VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="background"  VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="lookAndFeel"  VALUE="Oracle">
<PARAM NAME="colorScheme"  VALUE="teal">
<PARAM NAME="serverApp" VALUE="default">
<PARAM NAME="logo" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="imageBase" VALUE="codebase">
<PARAM NAME="formsMessageListener" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="recordFileName" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="EndUserMonitoringEnabled" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="EndUserMonitoringURL" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="heartBeat" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="MaxEventWait" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="allowAlertClipboard" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="disableValidateClipboard" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="enableJavascriptEvent" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="MAYSCRIPT" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="digitSubstitution" VALUE="context">
<PARAM NAME="legacy_lifecycle" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="JavaScriptBlocksHeartBeat" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="highContrast" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="disableMDIScrollbars" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="clientDPI" VALUE="">
<PARAM name="applet_stop_timeout" value="800">
<PARAM name="guiMode" value="0">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could download the JAR and try to run it with:

```
java.exe -jar jarfile.jar
```

You should also check if there are any options set for the JAR in the HTML source of the page (things like connection info etc.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to run an Oracle Forms Application/Applet outside the Browser.

There is a tool which does exactly that: [Forms EXEJar](http://www.talkingbyte.com/)

You just run that with the URL of your Forms Application and it creates an executable JAR file from your Forms application. This also works around all the typical Internet Explorer crash issues etc as it is browser independent.

Hope that helps,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Download the remote JAR file.

Also download the source for the web page (save the page as HTML).

Edit the downloaded HTML (in notepad or your favorite text editor) to use the path to your local JAR file instead of the original URL. Be sure to update any non-local, relative URLs to include the original host name, unless you have that data downloaded locally as well.

Double click the edited HTML file to open it in a browser. It should all run locally now.

By the way, I noticed one parameter in particular:

```
<PARAM NAME="serverURL" VALUE="/forms/lservlet?ifcfs=/forms/frmservlet?config=pdev&#38;ifsessid=WLS_FORMS1.formsapp.1090&#38;acceptLanguage=en-US,en;q=0.8">
```

I don't know what this applet does but the fact that it takes some URL for some server it presumably connects to implies that you won't be able to run it without an internet connection anyways, so I'm not sure how much you gain by doing this.

If you're just looking for a quick way to run it from the desktop you could create a web link shortcut on your desktop that goes directly to the page with the applet on it.

Edit: Also, Google Chrome has a feature to create application shortcuts from web pages. [Grab Chrome if you don't have it](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) (setup is quick and painless) then go to the page with your applet. From the menu choose Tools -> Create Application Shortcuts. This will create a shortcut on the desktop (and optionally in the start menu) that, when clicked, will open the page in an application-style new window; no browser bars, no tabs, independent of any other browsing you are doing. It will bring you very close to the feel of a real desktop application and sounds like what you are going for.

Comment: I get tired of invoking applications from a bookmarked web page. It holds a tab open in my browser that if I close kills the app. Being able to run it directly just "feels" better to me.

Comment: @JohnO Google Chrome has a feature to create application shortcuts from web pages. Why don't you give this a try? Grab Chrome if you don't have it then go to the page with your applet. From the menu choose Tools -> Create Application Shortcuts. This will create a shortcut on the desktop (and optionally in the start menu) that, when clicked, will open the page in an application-style new window; no browser bars, no tabs, independent of any other browsing you are doing. It will bring you very close to the feel of a real desktop application and sounds like what you are going for.